# How to recover accidentally deleted cells in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm working in a .ipynb file in VSCode and I tried to undo some lines by using ESC + Z, but for some reason either I undid too much or I pressed something else, but around 30 of my cells all got deleted. I don't know how to redo and I'm scared I lost all my work!

How can I recover these cells???

Thanks

edit: I found the code that I've run using %history but I was hoping to get my Markdown cells as well because I wrote a lot of information there

edit 2: I noticed that my cells weren't just deleted, but my files actually just changed to a different spot in history, as my first few cells contained something different than it did before the cells disappeared. Does that change the answer to this question at all?

I did post a workaround to recover some stuff, but I'd still appreciate if someone let me know what happened in my 2nd edit, thanks!

Comment: %history works for the code that ran last. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: just lost some super frustrating cells I fixed!!!! Can you explain what you mean %history? edit: sorry, you mean type %history into the cell and run it

Comment: Similar to `%history`, if you know that your deleted cell ran at step 42, then `%recall 42` will insert that cell without the need of a copy-paste.

Answer (score 62):

If you hit the 'Z' key it will undo moves and deletes. Note, not CTRL+Z, but 'Z' by itself.  [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11106#issuecomment-614763069) to the GitHub issue.

Comment: I assume this works if you are not inside any cell. Didn't work for me on Windows.

Comment: omg, what's the point to undo a cell with merely one key and furthermore no recovery way avaliable.

Comment: If you click `Z` by accident and remove a cell, `CTRL` + `Y` (redo) will bring it back

Comment: Saved me big time, thanks! Very strange way of doing things though...

Comment: Just want to comment on another cell that was saved by this!
Thanks!

Comment: An old answer, but would to let you know that this is super helpfull

Comment: Pressing Z deleted my cells! I deselected all cells when I pressed it.

Comment: This did not work for me. Though I panicked and tried ctrl+z first, but then no Edit > Redo or ctrl+y yielded any changes. The cell stayed deleted :(

Answer (score 34):

I found a way to get the lost cells back, which saved me an enormous amount of time as I did not have to recreate those cells. If you open the timeline (bottom left corner of the screen), you can go back in time when you still had those cells, copy the content and paste it in a new cell.
Update: you might have to upgrade to the latest version if Timeline is not available for you.

Comment: You Legend!!! Never knew this tool existed :)

Comment: +1 indeed. The timeline thing was the only thing that worked in VSCode for me, specially when you have accidentally closed it and no 'Z' button can save you!

Comment: No idea why, but my timeline most recent is 2 weeks ago?

Answer (score 21):

I had a similar issue where I was hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> outside of the cell when I thought I was inside the cell (usually because running current cell makes you lose cell focus).
Sometime it just "undid" the last created cell somewhere else in my notebook, and I actually lost some cells because I didn't realized right away what happened and just continued working.

I thought I would share my solution to this problem (because Google sent me on this post, and more people might be interested).

Redefining the [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) worked for me.
**I removed the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut** when I'm not inside a cell (you can still access it with the menu `Edit > Undo`). I did the same for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, and so on.

To do this, I added theses rules to my [`keybindings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization):

```json
{ "key": "ctrl+z", "command": "-undo" },
{ "key": "ctrl+z", "command": "undo", "when": "!notebookEditorFocused || inputFocus" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+z", "command": "-redo" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+z", "command": "redo", "when": "!notebookEditorFocused || inputFocus" },
{ "key": "ctrl+y", "command": "-redo" },
{ "key": "ctrl+y", "command": "redo", "when": "!notebookEditorFocused || inputFocus" },
```

I also removed the <kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut from Jupyter extension because I don't like it.

```json
{ "key": "z", "command": "-undo", "when": "notebookEditorFocused && !inputFocus" },
```

Comment: I removed D D for cell deletion as well. By default, you can use "delete" to remove the cell

Comment: Great solution! I find undo handy within cells but not for cell actions (e.g., accidentally deleting recently created cell). So I edited the Undo keyboard shortcut's when variable to be 'textInputFocus' to only work within cells.

Comment: How did you implement this @WilsonSauthoff?

Comment: @NathanielRamm this is available in VSCode: Find the [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) in VSCode, search 'Undo', right click on 'When' field and change to 'textInputFocus' so that you can still use control(command)+z for in-cell undos but will not work for cell actions (e.g., undoing a cell addition).

Comment: @NathanielRamm: Add the following to disable the single-key hotkeys that can delete your cells: `{ "key": "z", "command": "-undo" },
{ "key": "x", "command": "-notebook.cell.cut" },
{ "key": "d d", "command": "-notebook.cell.delete" },`

Comment: It works like a charm in VSCode. For those who wonder how to find `keybindings.json` in VSCode: `ctrl+shif+p` -> `open keyboard shortcuts (JSON)`

Answer (score 14):

This happens constantly for me. So incredibly annoying! It happens when I hit or mishit CMD+Z. No amount of ESC-Z will recreate the deleted cell. Nothing in any menu have so far recreated the lost. I have deleted all shortcuts for 'delete cell' but it makes no difference at all. Just about to give up on VSCode for this reason alone.

Comment: My [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69421121/7420421) might interest you!

Comment: look at answer from @Akos here. straightforward clean solution

Answer (score 11):

This solution worked for me:

1. Open the command pallet (`ctrl+shift+p` on windows)
2. Select the "Undo" command

Not sure why it works. Does vscode disable the `ctrl-z` shortcut when outside a cell?

Comment: Worked for me on MacOS. (CMD+Shift+P)

Comment: Undo deleted more cells. Redo reverted them back for me.

Answer (score 9):

`%history` is a life saver but i will also note: When you run `%history` not all the code will show, given the amount of lines - you must navigate to the output file where you will see all the history, it is displayed there. The option to open the output file is usually given at the top of the page in VS code anyway.

Comment: I have updated my comment to contribute something new to the post - please delete your comment.

Comment: This is a lifesaver. For those like me who didnt know where to type this, please type it in a new cell and click "run"

Answer (score 7):

Ok, this is crazy but since I'm in Visual Studio Code, I tried right clicking on my .ipynb file and clicking "Convert to Python Script".

This recovered every single line including Markdown Code that I had before I did something to delete my cells.

Might be worth a try if you deleted your Jupyter Cells in Visual Studio Code

Comment: not work for me... might be because of the saved file you open.

Answer (score 1):

I am using vscode, here I put CTRL+M+Z

Comment: This just saved me the headache of recreating an intricate printing function! Best answer. Btw, for me the `M` is `shift`. So to becomes `ctrl`+`shift`+`z`

Answer (score 1):

The `ctrl + shift + z` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this thread after facing a similar situation as I lost a day's work as well but, I wasn't going to give up!
So, if you have setup Auto Save on VS Code and have wsl2 enabled and are using VS code from wsl, you have to navigate to this path

```
> \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\<user-name>\.vscode-server\data\User\History\.
```

or simply do

```
cd (to go to root path)
type explorer.exe . (this will open file explorer)
Navigate to .vscode-server\data\User\History\.
```

There will be multiple folders, pick one for the file you want to restore and Voila!

Answer (score 0):

just click Z in windows. This saves my a lot of pain. it happens sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Note that VSCode 1.78 (Apr. 2023) will come with a confirmation popup *before* deleting a cell!

This is from [issue 173481](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173481) which comments:

> Having just accidentally deleted a cell that had been running for over 4 hours, I'd like to suggest that there be a confirmation popup for running Jupyter cells to be deleted.
> Ideally there should be an option to confirm for all cells, but should be a default for cells that are currently executing.
>
> You can undo delete cell operations, but that wouldn't bring back an in-progress cell, so a confirmation on running cells sounds reasonable.

Hence, [PR 179776](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/179776), which is available in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) today.

```
This cell is running, are you sure you want to delete it?
```

Comment: This change does not prevent Ctrl-Z from removing a running cell when the notebook is not in focus. I just tried in v 1.78.2. with an infinite while loop, and there was no popup. The cell was just deleted without any notification or means of undeleting it.

Comment: @NathanielRamm Darn it! That is really unfortunate. I suspect |issue 173481](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173481) is not really resolved then.

Answer (score 0):

In Jupyter Notebooks on Windows, you can easily navigate both undo and redo actions:

Open the Command Palette using `(Ctrl + Shift + P)`.
Type and select "`Undo`" or "`Redo`" to go back and forth through your actions.
This shortcut can be a time-saver when you need to navigate your notebook's history efficiently.